# Spark Streaming with Kafka in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to build a Kafka consumer in Scala using IntelliJ to read messages from a Kafka topic and save them on hdfs. I'm using spark 1.6.2, kafka_2.10-0.10, scala 2.10.5 with hdp 2.5.3. I'm getting the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIILjava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol;)V
```

From my research on here, I've learned that it's a jar/dependency issue but I'm still not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that kafka libraries are available for Spark runtime. There are several ways to make sure of this:

1. Invoking spark shell or spark-submit with --jars "/location/of/your/kafka-jar"
2. Copy kafka related jars into your spark installation's "jars" folder. (Note: If you running on cluster, you have to copy these jars to all the nodes. So, I recommend above method where spark does this for you internally)

Comment: I'm using the --jars option with my spark submit command and providing paths for all the jars. Actually, I'm doing the second method too.

Comment: Then try to invoke 'spark-shell' command with its complete path with --jars option. Then in the shell, execute the statement : 

import kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer

Is it getting imported successfully?

Comment: Yes, it is getting imported successfully that way.

Comment: Then the reason for that exception should be incompatible Kafka library versions. Can you post the dependencies that you are including during your development?